# difference between Time.now() and /clock

Tags: ros, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!I'm new to ROS and now i have checked that to print time on screen (for example) i can use ros::Time::now() or subscribe to /clock and get time from the message.
Anybody can tell me if there are differencies between these two ways?
thanks,

max

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34055/difference-between-time.now()-and-/clock/) by [max](https://answers.ros.org/users/2383/max/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These two options represent the same time. In code, you should definitely use `ros::Time::now()`. It will get you the current ROS time that is being published to `/clock` without most of the overhead involved with subscribing to the topic yourself. Plus, it looks a lot better in your code.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-05-15**:
Isn't /clock only published by simulation and only used by ros::Time when use_sim_time is true? I think on a real system, subscribing to it would just not work.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-05-15**:
I believe you might be correct